# Create Function Contructor in Dart / Flutter ,Like new Function in javascript

Tags: flutter, dart

```js
//After parsing json / or after json decode
const jsonDecoded = {
     body:`if (title == 'ball') {
      return pri + 10;
    } else if (title == 'bag') {
      return pri + 20;
    } else if (title == 'shoes') {
      return pri + 30;
    } else {
      return pri;
    }`,
    args:"pri,title"
}


 
    
    const priceCalculator = new Function(jsonDecoded.args, jsonDecoded.body);
    
    const price = priceCalculator(10, 'shoes');
    console.log(price);
```

In javascript, we can construct function

count not find a way to create a function in flutter or dart.
Could someone convert the above code to DART/FLUTTER
I would be blessed if someone could guide me.

Comment: if its not return any specific  value, you can use `void`

Answer (score 0):

You can create function like this and value on callback

```dart
  final Function(int data, String args) myfun;
```

Dart

```dart
double priceCalculator(
  double pri,
  String title,
) {
  if (title == 'ball') {
    return pri + 10;
  } else if (title == 'bag') {
    return pri + 20;
  } else if (title == 'shoes') {
    return pri + 30;
  } else {
    return pri;
  }
}

 final Map<double, String> arg = {0: "myPrince"};

  final double print = priceCalculator(arg.keys.first, arg.values.first);
```

Example on flutter will be

```dart
 TEX(
  myfun: (data, args) {},
)
```

```dart
class TEX extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function(int data, String args) myfun;
  const TEX({
    Key? key,
    required this.myfun,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
        myfun(2, "args");
      }),
      
    );
  }
```

Comment: `const body = `if (title == 'ball') {
  return pri + 10;
} else if (title == 'bag') {
  return pri + 20;
} else if (title == 'shoes') {
  return pri + 30;
} else {
  return pri;
}`;

const arg = 'pri,title';

const priceCalculator = new Function(arg, body);

const price = priceCalculator(10, 'shoes');`

Comment: you cant use `const` it it is not compile time final, you can use final for that.

Comment: Can you please recheck my post and convert that to flutter dart,

Comment: You created a function that is not what I want. I want to create a function from a string .Can you see args and body both are string

Comment: If you double check my post you will have better understanding

Comment: it might not be possible from string , as much i know